# Can't sign in when using Opera Turbo

Tags: support, login

I'm trying to sign in to my account via Google, but when I use Opera Mobile with Opera Turbo enabled, it does not let me on, saying that my request was suspicious. However, when I disable Turbo, it lets me on. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Stack Exchange network thing, and the general explanation ([as described on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170923/150283)) is:

> We don't usually require sticky IPs (in particular once you're logged
>   in it shouldn't be an issue), but if during the process of logging in
>   your IP address changes, that's extremely fishy, and that's why we
>   bail out.

It's hard to say for certain why this would be happening, but my guess would be that Opera's Turbo service is distributed over a number of proxy servers, and so your requests in the middle of the log in process ended up coming from different physical servers, and therefore resolved to different IP addresses. Turning off Turbo would cause all requests to originate from your device without travelling through the proxy, so it would make sense that doing so would prevent the rapidly changing IPs and allow you to log in.